# What is more efficient when updating the state of a list in react? Using Shallow Copies or slicing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I have a CartStruct interface which holds a property cartObj of type CartObj. The CartObj interface holds many properties. One of which is the cartNumber.

This is the mockup of the interfaces

```
const interface CartStruct {
  cartObj: CartObj
  pos: number
}

const interface CartObj {
  ...
  cartNumber: number
  ...
}
```

In a form, a user can input data for multiple CartStructs, and so I made a useState that stores a CartStruct array.

`const [cart, setCart] = useState<CartStruct[]>([])`

When the user changes the value of the cartNumber, I've found two ways to do it. One using shallow copy and this is by far more readable. The other method is to slice. It is more direct and it's definitely less readable. However, which one is more efficient? Does the fact that you're avoiding the shallow copy in the second one make the code more efficient? Is there another reason as to why one is better than the other?

Here are the methods

Method 1: Using Shallow Copies

```
const lst = [...cart]
lst[index].cartObj.cartNumber = e.target.value
setCart(lst)
```

Method 2: Direct approach

```
setCart([
  ...cart.slice(0, index), {
    ...cart[index], 
    cartObj: {
      ...cart[index].cartObj, 
      cartNumber: e.target.value
    }
  },
  ...cart.slice(index + 1)
])
```

Comment: from what I can see those two solutions give two different results, in that the first is amending an array item in place, the second always appends a new one to the end?

Comment: You're right! I misunderstood how the brackets worked. Thanks for point this out @andymccullough I'll fix it now

Comment: Your question is unclear as both methods you are asking about create shallow copies of an array. Your method 1, however, is mutating the state object because it isn't also creating shallow copies of any nested state that is being updated. Questions that are phrased in a superlative way tend to also be off-topic on SO. What sort of efficiency are you specifically referring to? If you are just wanting to update a specific index then I'd posit that using `Array.prototype.map` would be more efficient than either method you've mentioned, both in performance *and* readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Method 2 is also a shallow copy, you start by doing `...cart`.

The difference is that in Method 2 you also shallow copy all the objects in the path to your change - this is called an immutable update.
btw, there are libraries that can do it for you, to make it more readable, like: [react immutability helper](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html) or [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/).

Method 1 is slightly faster.
but Method 2 is more correct. Because although React renders all the child components when a parent is rendered by default, you might memoize one of the child components (using React.memo) and then this component will only render if its' props or state changed by reference (unless you use context).

One final note, I don't know how many items you have in the cart. And nothing about your state management. But if it's a very long list of items and performance matters you might want to pass the parent component only a list of itemIds and let the child component get the correct item by id. This way the parent component won't render when a field is changed inside an item.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you @Alissa for your helpful response. I understand better now and I started using Immer. It shortned a lot of my code.